# SSRS Report using Stored Procedure returning 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report using a stored procedure to return data. The report is only showing the headers and no data, I can also get the parameters to show.

When I ran a trace it shows the query with the parameters that I would expect and when I run that same query through SSMS I get 3 records.

I looked at the report server and I am getting a 0 row count but a status of success.

I also tried changing the stored procedure to return specific fields instead of selecting all from my temp table.

I have triple checked that the data source and data sets are set up like other reports and I have also checked to make sure that nothing is hidden. I also made a couple of the fields a smaller font to make sure that wasn't it either.

Lastly I deleted the .dat file for this report.

Here is my test stored procedure that also returned 0 rows to the report, but returns 61 records when run in SSMS.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Polo_ExpPackSlipItemsLoadSp] 
    @PL_Num INT,
    @job JobType,
    @suffix SuffixType
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        'test' AS pl_num, 'data' AS item 
    FROM
        polo_exp_plitem pli
END
```

When I run the stored procedure with the same parameters that I am passing to the SSRS report, I get 3 records. The report fields come back empty.

Comment: does your report server has the same data source connection as the correct result you ran based on?

Comment: Does your dataset pass these params across to the DB?

Comment: I believe so. I run the report through a third party application and it just passes a connection string. I compared it to the connection string that other reports use and it appears to be the same.

Comment: The parms are the same:  pPL_Num=67&pJob=imp0002194&pSuffix=0 And this is what I'm actually running it with: @PL_Num=N'67',@job=N'imp0002194',@suffix=N'0'

Comment: What do you mean "ran a trace"?  What tool(s) did you use?  Also, what happens if you remove the `From` clause from that test stored procedure, and why would parameters affect the output (there's no `Where` clause)?

Comment: I used SQL server profiler. I finally got data to show. It looks like it was something that wasn't being done in the third party software I am using that I assumed was being done automatically. Thanks for your help everyone!